# Which was the first OS having both isolated users and programs?

Tags: operating-system

Multi-user OSes are nothing special. Normally one user cannot access the files of another user. Installed programs are shared. User's are running in a sandbox and they're isolated from other users.

Isolated programs are not that common. It forbids one program to access the files of another program.

Imagine you are using a web browser and you're also storing passwords for websites (so you do not have to enter them again). The passwords are stored obfuscated but unencrypted in a local file in your home directory. Now when you run a game (downloaded from the internet) it can normally read all your passwords. (AFAIK this is still the case for modern browsers today if you are not using a master password.)

On smartphones (Android + iOS) this is different (and in my opinion better). Apps cannot read the files and settings of other apps. Because apps are isolated it's also possible to restrict other permissions like camera access or access to your geographical location.

Which was the first OS having both user and program isolation? At least programs must not have been able to read files of other programs. Also note it must have been possible without modifying the OS, changing configuration files or installing tools.

Also note that the answer "every multi-user OS can be used to isolate programs" does not count. Because to be a valid answer the OS has to be used in a normal way. Manually creating a user for each program on Windows or Debian means the OS is **not** used in a normal way.

To meet the condition for being a multi-user OS it must be possible for multiple real persons to use one single device (every person has its own user). Also each user must have his own settings for each program (because the settings are stored in the user's home directory for example).

I am looking for all kind of OSes (not only desktop).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142608/discussion-on-question-by-zomega-which-was-the-first-os-having-both-isolated-use); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Suppose we change the spelling of "user id" to "program id", without changing the underlying implementation,  Presto, we've solved the problem,  right?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest CTSS (1961), which I believe isolated users/programs by swapping jobs in and out of memory rather than paging.

This built on earlier batched systems which had implicit separation since each program ran sequentially, hence there was no interaction at all between users.

Later, VM/370 allowed user programs to pass messages between themselves, which was used to implement various larger-scale networking etc.

All in all, I would suggest that "which is the first OS that allowed controlled interaction between user programs including OS-provided subsystems" would be a more interesting question.

---

If I may make a personal observation about the very early OSes that led up to CTSS etc. In the beginning a program, compiled or in source form, was submitted with no prefix or suffix.

At some point it became usual to load each program with prefix and/or suffix code to set up peripherals; this might or might not have included library routines for use while the program was running.

That changed to having prefix/suffix control cards, which were processed by a memory-resident monitor (not, in theory at least, overwritten or disabled by the user program).

And it was that memory-resident monitor which handled job setup, which became the in-memory OS of the early '60s with task switching one of its responsibilities.

Comment: That isolates programs while they’re running, but could a program access another program’s data in storage? Note that in the question, the browser doesn’t have to be running for the game to access the (poorly-protected, which might not be accurate) passwords.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm not sure, but the description I've seen suggests that every active user had his own storage device and this was what was used for the swapping. Early timeshaing was /slow/: even something like a B5500 (1964ish) only had around one tick per second (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Ah yes, in very early versions of CTSS, “We did not have any disk storage, so we took advantage of the fact that it was a large machine and we had a lot of tape drives. We assigned one tape drive per typewriter.” (Rosin and Lee, The CTSS Interviews, in _Annals of the History of Computing 14_, 1992.) Thus storage was separate, at least in that version.

Comment: @StephenKitt I believe that IBM did something very similar for APL/360, which they positioned as an "everybody can have a calculator at their desk" product; however by then they had disk storage. I don't know where in-memory multitasking started, but I find Burroughs' claim for the B5000 persuasive... and I think one of the oral histories states that was at least on part based on presentations at one of the (E?)JCCs so there might have been predecessor research-grade systems.

Comment: @StephenKitt thinking about your original point: programs/users on a 7000-series machine could probably have found some way of accessing each others peripherals, but it would hardly have been an "officially sanctioned" interface. My understanding is that IBM mainframes relied on "security by obscurity" well into the MVS era, at which point they had a massive exercise tightening things up (sorry, I've lost the reference to that). I'm not necessarily saying that their competitors were much better, although it might have taken more stages and a modicum of social engineering to really break things

Comment: Is this OS just like a normal Linux where CUPS and Apache run as own users? Because then it does not count because CUPS and Apache are system services and not user programs. I am looking for an OS where user programs can be shared across users. Each user can have his **own settings** for this program. Simply creating a user for each program is not what I am looking for. On Android you can have two users playing the same game. Each user has its **own save state**. This is possible with all apps on Android. Is CTSS like Android or is it not?

Comment: @zomega if you're interested in Android etc. then why are you asking about multi-user OSes, and for that matter why are you asking about a current OS here?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I am asking about a fundamental thing (not an Android thing) which in my opinion will be introduced in all OSes in the future. I thought there was an OS long before Android and iOS which had this but it seems this was a mistake.

Comment: ATLAS?  Virtual memory + concurrent programs.  1961/1962?

Comment: What is the technical basis on which you distinguish 'system services' (when said services, such as Apache are not part of the operating system) from 'user programs'?

Comment: *"Is CTSS like Android or not?"*  Uh, I don't know.  Is a painting on a cave wall like online streaming?  There's an uncrossable gulf there somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the first, but the Titan Supervisor (1963, Cambridge University) came close.

Timesharing.
Interactive access.
Access control system.

Most notably, the access control lists on objects allowed one to grant or deny access to programs as well as users.  This I think is the crux of your question, right?

---

> The filing system, designed by A.G. Fraser, was very similar to that
> of the CTSS, though  with considerably more flexible arrangements for
> access control. In particular it was possible to use the identity  of
> a program as a parameter for access control decisions as well as or
> instead of the identity of the user, a  feature which Cambridge people
> have ever since regarded as strange to omit.

[IEEE biography of M.V.Wilkes](https://history.computer.org/pioneers/pdfs/W/Wilkes.pdf)

---

[Titan](https://cucps.soc.srcf.net/titan/) was the prototype for a system sold commerically as the Ferranti Atlas 2. It was essentially 'Atlas without the virtual memory', i.e. a cheaper machine - a steal at only a million pounds or so. It was not a desktop system.

The (bundled) supervisor thus has some claim to be the first timesharing system delivered commercially.

Comment: so, "atlas without the virtual memory" - then, perhaps it was Atlas that was first?  VM, concurrent programs running, _completed_ in 1962 but started earlier? https://history-computer.com/atlas-computer/ - but, wow, great find, especially a site where they're putting documents online!

Comment: I don't think so; the access-control scheme is a property of the OS, and the Titan Supervisor (written at Cambridge) is not as far as I can tell based on the earlier Atlas Supervisor (written at Manchester).  And my guess is that file protection only gets to be interesting when you have online shared storage (i.e., disks with file systems).  My assumption, of course, is that the OP is asking about protection of persistent data, not address spaces. I accept that magtapes probably are a grey area.

Comment: I agree with another-dave, the Atlas [didn’t have shared storage](http://curation.cs.manchester.ac.uk/atlas/elearn.cs.man.ac.uk/_atlas/docs/The%20Atlas%20story.pdf) (programs couldn’t arbitrarily access each others’ input or output) so it doesn’t meet zomega’s requirements.